# open file and printf the some things

Tags: c

In my c code fprintf not work properly.

```
fp2=fopen(file_name,"w");
fprintf(fp2,"%s %c %s %c %s %c %c %f\n","Result",'(',arr1,',',arr2,')', '=',result);
```

I write like this but the file opens and there is no words in the file.

I think the file is deleted every time I call it function because it reopens. However, I want the data to be kept in the file when the program is finished, and if there is data in the file, I want it to be deleted and write it.

Comment: add `fclose(fp2);`; add check before fprintf: `if (fp2 == NULL) { perror(file_name); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: I add  my code but still does not work

Comment: Please [edit] show a [mcve]. There is not enough information in your question. The problem is probably somewhere in code you didn't show

Comment: BTW: Why don't you write this, which is far more simple and far more readable: `fprintf(fp2,"Result(%s,%s)=%f\n" ,arr1, arr2, result);`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I think the file is deleted every time I call it function because it reopens. However, I want the data to be kept in the file when the program is finished, and if there is data in the file, I want it to be deleted and write it.

Comment: @user3121023 I think the file is deleted every time I call it function because it reopens. However, I want the data to be kept in the file when the program is finished, and if there is data in the file, I want it to be deleted and write it.

Comment: @pmg I think the file is deleted every time I call it function because it reopens. However, I want the data to be kept in the file when the program is finished, and if there is data in the file, I want it to be deleted and write it.

Comment: @an you don't need to write the same comment 3 times. The problem with the file being deleted is normal behaviour. Each time you do `fopen(filename, "w");` the file is recreated from scratch. Maybe you want to _append_ to the file? You write: _"However, I want the data to be kept in the file when the program is finished, and if there is data in the file, I want it to be deleted and write it."_ This is contradictory, you need to elaborate this.